# How to implement an (auto) Logout feature in MAUI?

Tags: logout, maui

I have another question, please.

I have a shell-based navigation:

```
<Shell ...
    <Shell.Items>
        <ShellContent x:Name="Login" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Login:Login}" Route="Login" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" ></ShellContent>
    </Shell.Items>

    <TabBar Route="Login">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Login:Login}" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" ></ShellContent>
    </TabBar>

    <TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar" Shell.NavBarHasShadow="true" Route="Home">        
        <Tab Title="Tab1" ... >
            <ShellContent Title="Page1"
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Page2"
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Tab2" ... >
            <ShellContent Title="Page3"
            </ShellContent>
            <ShellContent Title="Page4"
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Tab3"... >
            <ShellContent Title="Page5"
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I need to implement a Logout feature.

If I create a Flyout containing just this Logout button I am afraid that it won't be at all visible or intuitive or obvious for the users.

I would like to set it up in some linkButton residing to the right of my TabBar, thus showing, for instance,
Page1 Page2         Logout
and
Page3 Page4         Logout
and
Page5               Logout

but unfortunately I do not know how to insert a button there.

I could maybe set it up it on the last page, Page5, somwehere (that's what I've been told to do by my manager - I do not agree with that position - again, it's not at all obvious).

But no matter where I set this button, I don't know how to clear the nav history (to kill that back arrow).

I have tried to write this code on that button:

```
[RelayCommand]
        private static async void Logout()
        {
            try
            {
                Globals.loginStatus = Globals.LoginStatus.loginRefused;
                await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Login), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to logout: {ex.Message}");
                Utils.ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }
```

together with this (in Shell.cs):

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigating(args);

    // Cancel any back navigation.
    if (args.Source == ShellNavigationSource.Pop)
    {
        args.Cancel();
    }
}
```

This does not do me any good - I can still see the Back arrow one the Login tab. I can also see the three tabs on the bottom: Tab1, Tab2, and Tab3, enabled, and I shouldn't be able to see those !

By reversing the order of the calls

```
[RelayCommand]
        private static async void Logout()
        {
            try
            {
                Globals.loginStatus = Globals.LoginStatus.loginRefused;
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Login), true);
                await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to logout: {ex.Message}");
                Utils.ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }
```

the result is even funnier: the app flip-flops between Page5 and Login.

So, my questions are:

1. Where should I set this Logout button up ? In the case there is a way to put it in the TabBar (my first choice), how ?
2. What do you think about putting it into some FlyOut on the Login page ?
3. What should I do to really kill the back navigation ? How could I also hide the TabBar items by code from this method in Page5 ?
4. I could maybe just say Application.Current.Quit(); but this is not quite elegant, is it ? Besides, this might not work in iOS.
5. Since this app works with sensitive data, I would like to write an auto-logout feature, to be executed after, say, one minute of inactivity. It's very simple to do this in Windows (using Windows api) but how would one do it in MAUI ?

Thank you !
Alex

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: It sounds like you want the app to **quit** (not just log out the user). Mobile platforms don't support that (iOS) or strongly discourage that (Android). Therefore, it is not a cross-platform feature, so will not exist in Maui (or cross-platform .Net). Read about how to write platform-specific code in Maui, to support that on Windows.

Comment: `Application.Current.Quit()` work on the andorid and the windows, but it doesn't work for the ios.